# Weird line in <head> in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I just started a new Typo3 4.6 site and I found this weird line right off the bat in the

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css,">
```

Where does it come from? And how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been added from some extension. I used the introductory package. Ive done a new site with the blank package and its not there anymore. Thanks!

Comment: You should not use the `Introduction` package to create a site. It is solely for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the css stylesheet which creates the styles for the pages in your Typo3 CMS. You probably need this line and might want to keep it.

Comment: It doesnt point to any file. I havent made any stylesheet yet. its a brand new blank site.

Comment: Is it prepping for when you do add a stylesheet?